# Define a subset of a metric space that is both open and closed.

Tags: metric-spaces

Define a nonempty subset of a metric space that is both open and closed.

The real line with the Euclidean metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ is open and closed. If you take two real lines, not connected together, and invent a metric that works for any pair of points (it has to be able to give a distance if one point is on one line and one is on the other, as well as a distance between two points on the same line), then you have a nice disconnected metric space. And one of the lines is a closed open subset.

(Provided you can make sure there's a minimum distance between pairs of points on different lines)

I'm having some trouble with metric spaces and can't think of a subset that would be both open and closed (except for empty subset).

Comment: Take the empty set.

Comment: ahh sorry should've said a nonempty subset

Comment: I suppose the whole space is not allowed either?

Comment: Any set with the discrete topology is metrizable, and any subset of a discrete topological space is both open and closed, so...there you go!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496235/proving-the-every-subset-of-m-is-clopen

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is connected, which means it cannot be written as the disjoint union of non-empty open sets.  Equivalently, if $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is open and closed, then either $S=\emptyset$ or $S=\mathbb{R}^{n}$. You have to find a topology where the underlying space is disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered in comments:

> Any set with the discrete topology is metrizable, and any subset of a discrete topological space is both open and closed, so...there you go! –  Nick D. Jan 15 at 0:50
>
> [Proving the every subset of $M$ is clopen.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496235/proving-the-every-subset-of-m-is-clopen) –  Poppy Jan 15 at 2:03

Note that:

> $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected, which means it cannot be written as the disjoint union of non-empty open sets. Equivalently, if $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is open and closed, then either $S=\emptyset$ or $S=\mathbb{R}^n$. You have to find a topology where the underlying space is disconnected. –  T.A.E. Jan 15 at 5:48